# Extracting Part of XML from Other XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am having task to extract a part of XML file from my source XML file. I am new to XSLT part but i tried to write XSLT but not getting any luck in fetching right data.

For example I am having XML like

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns="https://insuredapp.com/rating/" id="24d846677aefd1bd7fdf52286e692a22">
    <Result type="request">
        <abc>
            <bcd>

            </bcd>
        </abc>
    </Result>
    <Result type="response">
        <InsuranceSvcRs>
            <PersPkgPolicyQuoteInqRs>
                <PersPolicy>
                    <Coverage>
                        <!--- Some MOre Elemetns -->
                    </Coverage>
                    <Coverage>
                        <!--- Some MOre Elemetns -->
                    </Coverage>
                    <Coverage>
                        <!--- Some MOre Elemetns -->
                    </Coverage>
                </PersPolicy>
            </PersPkgPolicyQuoteInqRs>
        </InsuranceSvcRs>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

After applying XSLT transform I want output to be

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Coverages>
    <Coverage>
        <!--- Some More Elements -->
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <!--- Some More Elements -->
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <!--- Some More Elements -->
    </Coverage>
</Coverages>
```

To extract above coverages using XSLT I had written following XSLT Code

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Response/Result[@type='response']/InsuranceSvcRs/PersPkgPolicyQuoteInqRs/PersPolicy">
        <!--<xsl:for-each select="/Response/Result[@type='response']/InsuranceSvcRs/PersPkgPolicyQuoteInqRs/PersPolicy/Coverage">
            <xsl:value-of select="CoverageCd"/>
        </xsl:for-each>-->

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/Response/Result[@type='response']/InsuranceSvcRs/PersPkgPolicyQuoteInqRs/PersPolicy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I am not getting desired output kindly look into it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a *default namespace* in your input document:

```
<Response xmlns="https://insuredapp.com/rating/">
```

If you'd like to select individual elements from this input, you have to *redeclare* this namespace in the XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:resp="https://insuredapp.com/rating/">
```

Start with a template that matches `/` (the document node), output `Coverages` and use the `xsl:copy-of` instruction.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:resp="https://insuredapp.com/rating/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="resp">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <Coverages xmlns="https://insuredapp.com/rating/">
          <xsl:copy-of select="//resp:Coverage"/>
       </Coverages>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Coverages xmlns="https://insuredapp.com/rating/">
   <Coverage>
      <!--- Some MOre Elemetns -->
   </Coverage>
   <Coverage>
      <!--- Some MOre Elemetns -->
   </Coverage>
   <Coverage>
      <!--- Some MOre Elemetns -->
   </Coverage>
</Coverages>
```

Note that the elements in the output are still in a namespace. It is not clear whether you'd like to get rid of that namespace.

Comment: @Faiz If this answer was helpful to you, then please accept it. Thanks! Here is how accepting an answer works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.